# Custom CSS in iFrame Widget (React, MUI)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, iframe, material-ui

I'm trying to customize a fiat-to-crypto onramp widget so that I can overwrite the current style for one that matches my react app.

This is a reactjs app, using material ui. This widget exists in an iFrame.

Someone has already managed to do it: https://app.rubic.exchange/buy-crypto?_ga=2.79437588.1459597697.1646699276-647485347.1645485242

I've checked out their work on inspect, but can't seem to replicate it in my react app.

I've tried two methods:

**METHOD ONE**

Locating the contentWindow.document - unfortunately this did not work as there is no document visible when queried:

```
function changeStuff() {
    const onramperWindow = onramper.contentWindow;
    console.log(onramperWindow)
    const onramperDocument = onramperWindow.document
    console.log(onramperDocument)
 }
```

This results in an error as the document does not seem to be available other than in the parent, which is not what I'm looking to edit.

**METHOD TWO**

As my react app uses MUI, I've tried utilizing useStyles.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    embedContainer: {
      "& iframe": {
          position: "absolute",
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: "50%",
          height: "100%",
          color: "#000000"
      }
    }
  });
```

Followed by the iframe:

```
<iframe
id="onramper"
src="https://widget.onramper.comcolor=346eeb&apiKey=pk_test_x5M_5fdXzn1fxK04seu0JgFjGsu7CH8lOvS9xZWzuSM0"
height="595px"
width="800px"
title="Onramper widget"
frameborder="no"
allow="accelerometer;
autoplay; camera; gyroscope; payment"
className={classes.embedContainer}
>
<a href="https://widget.onramper.com" target="_blank">Buy crypto</a>
</iframe>
```

However, using this method the entire screen is black, as it's injecting the css over the whole page.

Anyone have any guidance/tips/tutorials I can look at to customize the CSS on this iframe widget?

Answer (score -1):

By default the browser has a security system that encapsulates iframes preventing them from communicating with each other and with your page. It is not possible to circumvent this nor should it be.

Imagine you creating a fakebank.com with a bank.com iframe. Monitoring and getting user information smoothly.

But you can download the iframe content and insert it on your page that way you have full access.

ex:
**jquery:**

```js
$('#divframe').load(
    'http://www.corsproxy.com/' +
    'www.cptec.inpe.br/widget/widget.php?p=3819&amp;w=h&amp;c=474647&amp;f=ffffff .tabtop',  function() {
         $('#divframe').html( $('#divframe').html().replace(new RegExp('src="', 'g'),'src="http://www.cptec.inpe.br/widget/') );
    });
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="divframe"></div>
```

**Alternative with own proxy in PHP:**

**proxy.php** (with just that content, and nothing else)

```php
<?php
$cache_file = 'proxy_cache.html'; // name file to save cache

if (!@file_exists($cache_file) || (time() - @filemtime($cache_file) > (60 * 60 * 6))) { // check cache expirated and try new request
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.cptec.inpe.br/widget/widget.php?p=3819&amp;w=h&amp;c=474647&amp;f=ffffff");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $retorno = str_replace('src="','src="http://www.cptec.inpe.br/widget/',curl_exec($ch)); // add full address in all src
    curl_close($ch);
    file_put_contents($cache_file, $retorno); // save content in file cache
} else { // cache not expire, open file content wingthout new request
    $retorno = file_get_contents($cache_file);
}

echo $retorno; // print content
?>
```

**The content below must be in another file** along with the css and everything

**jquery:**

```js
$('#divframe').load(
    'proxy.php .tabtop',  function() {
        $('#divframe .tab_content').hide();
        $('#divframe .tabs li:first').addClass('active');
        $('#divframe .tab_content:first').show();
        $('#divframe .tabs li').click(function(){
            $('#divframe .tabs li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('#divframe .tab_content').hide();
            $($(this).children('a').attr('href')).show();
        });
    });
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="divframe"></div>
```

Sorry my english is not my native language =D

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it this way.